# VueJS: How to get parent's markup passed into child's `<slot>` when the child is visited directly(via router)?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

In Vue, (is it even possible on) how to get parent's markup passed into child's `<slot>` when the child is visited directly (via router) i.e.

**PARENT**

```
 <template>
   <child>
       <h2 slot="title">Title - child</h2>
       <p slot="content"> Lorem ipsum dolor immet... </p>
   </child>
 </template>
```

**CHILD**

```
 <template>
   <slot name="title"></slot>
   <slot name="content"></slot>
 </template>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the child is being visited directly (i.e. you have a route whose component is `Child` and that route is active) then the slots can only be set by the `<router-view>` that is rendering the child.

e.g.

**Parent**

```vue
<router-view>
  <h2 slot="title">Foo</h2>
</router-view>
```

**Child**

```vue
<div>
  <header><slot name="title"></slot></header>
  <section><slot name="content"></slot></section>
</div>
```

Then rendered DOM will look like:

```html
<div>
  <header><h2>Foo</h2></header>
  <section></section>
</div>
```

If the parent renders an instance of the child by itself (as shown in your code example) then this has nothing to do with the router, and the child that is rendered by the router isn't associated with the separate child rendered by the parent.

If you can provide some more context as to what you are trying to achieve, I can help you further.